# Best way to use observable once

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, firebase-authentication

The code below does the following:

The upload function below is being called on a file input when it changed. As you can see it creates a message with the uploaded image.

I get the user data from the user observable in the authService class (this user observable is received by firestore).

Once the message is created, a server-side trigger will update the number of messages the user has send (increment counter). This results in the user object being updated in the database. **Since this is an observable, the logic starts again and the code keeps upload images (infinite loop).**

**Is there a better way to get the userId (without observable), or to only execute the function once? What's the best, cleanest and most valid approach here?**

```js
    upload(fileEvent) {

        const message = new Message();
        message.createdAt = new Date();
        message.fileLocation = 'loc';
        message.receivedAt = null;
        message.receivedMessageId = null;
        message.receivedUserId = null;

        this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
          message.sendUserId = user.userId;
          message.sendScreenName = user.screenName;

          const messageImage = fileEvent.target.files[0];

          this.messageService.createMessage(message, messageImage);

          user.un
        });
      }
```

Comment: Try to put a parent component then pass the userId to a child by userId$ | async and put the upload function directly in it.

Comment: `user.un` what ? `.unsubscribe()` ?

Comment: usually you just want `take(1)` or `takeUntil(foo$)`. See  https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is an observable at some point something should satisfy it to `not` "observe", or, trigger your `authService` under a different condition.

First, at what point is `upload(fileEvent)` called. Check your `Network` tab in brwser `developer tools` and trace the component/service in `Sources` to see why it is being called so many times.

Next: use rxjs `pipe` that way to can "pipe" all your rxjs methods accordingly.

```
this.authService.user
 .pipe(
  tap(user => {
      message.sendUserId = user.userId;
      message.sendScreenName = user.screenName;
      const messageImage = fileEvent.target.files[0];

      this.messageService.createMessage(message, messageImage);
   })
  ).subscribe();
```

If your call is truly not recursive and it is only triggered on file input try the following. I currently do the same thing in my file upload component form. When the upload form changes it triggers the service call which is an observe. The observable will only react when it has something on which to react.

Also make sure to `unsubscribe` after each `subscribe()` Maybe `NetanelBasal/ngx-take-until-destroy` can help where you would use

```
  this.authService.user
    .pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map(user => {
       message.sendUserId = user.userId;
       message.sendScreenName = user.screenName;
       const messageImage = fileEvent.target.files[0];

       this.messageService.createMessage(message, messageImage);
     }),
     untilDestroyed(this)
    ).subscribe();
```

Other than that, investigate why the `authService` is being hit so many times. Or maybe if